# jest cannot resolve module aliases

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, alias

I am using a npm module called module-alias. I map some modules in tsconfig.json and package.json

**tsconfig.json**

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "baseUrl": "./src",
   "paths": {
   "@config/*": ["config/*"],
   "@interfaces/*": ["interfaces/*"],
   "@services/*": ["services/*"]
  },
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "es2015",                   /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
  "sourceMap": true,
  "outDir": "./dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
  "rootDir": "./src",    
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true          /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
}
```

package.json

```
  ...
 "_moduleAliases": {
    "@config": "src/config",
    "@interface": "src/interface",
    "@services": "src/services"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@config/(.*)": "src/config/$1",
      "@interface/(.*)": "src/interface/$1",
      "@services/(.*)": "src/services/$1"
    },

     "moduleFileExtensions": ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node']
  },
...
```

**server.ts**

```
import { logger } from '@config/logger';
```

everything works fine when I run `npm start`, but it gives me an error when I run jest

```
FAIL  src/test/article.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@config/logger' from 'server.ts'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        'rest/server.ts'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].
```

Anyone know what the problem is? thanks

**Solution works for me (Update 18/10/2019) :**

Create a jest.config.js with code below:

```
module.exports = {
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>/src/"
],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  }

}
```

**and update moduleNameMapper in package.json:**

```
...
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@config": "./src/config",
    "@interfaces": "./src/interfaces",
    "@services": "./src/services"
  },
  "jest": {

    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@config/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/config/$1",
      "@interfaces/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/interfaces/$1",
      "@services/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/services/$1"
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: You should remove your solution from your question and add your own answer.

Comment: How come you're not getting multiple config files found error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After a few hours I've managed to make this work. I'll try my best to simplify it to save others time and make it smooth.

My app is of the following stack:

- Typescript (`tsc` and `ts-node/register`, no Babel) for the API build (`.ts`)
- React (`.tsx` using Webpack)
- `jest` for API testing (no Babel)
- `testcafe` for UI/E2E
- VSCode as IDE

**Key notes:**

1. The solution that works for me is must have "**@**" character in front of the alias. It's not required in theory by `module-alias`, however Jest is getting lost when we apply the module name mapper.
2. There needs to be consistency for naming between 'webpack' aliases and 'tsconfig'. It is necessary for VSCode not to *red underline* module names in TSX files.
3. This should work regardless of your document structure but remember to adapt `baseUrl` and jest config if encounter issues.
4. When applying changes in VSCode for `.tsx` files do not be worried that some of the paths are underlined. It's temporary as VSCode seems to grasp it only when all files are correctly connected to each other. It demotivated me at the start.

First, install `module-alias` from https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias with

```
npm i --save module-alias
```

then add to your initial startup file (for `.ts` files only, i.e. your application server):

```
require('module-alias/register')
```

as the `module-alias` docs indicate. Then setup `tsconfig.ts`. Keep it mind that `baseUrl` is relevant here as well:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    ...
    "paths": {
      "@helpers/*": ["src/helpers/*"],
      "@root/*": ["src/*"]
      ...
    }
 }
```

then setup your `webpack.js`:

```
const path = require('path')
...
{
  resolve: {
    ...
    alias: {
      '@helpers': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'helpers'),
      '@root': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    }
  }
}
```

then setup your `package.json`:

```
{
   ...
   "_moduleAliases": {
     "@helpers": "src/helpers",
     "@root": "src"
   }
}
```

then setup your `jest` config (I attach only things that were relevant when applying my change):

```
{
   rootDir: ".",
   roots: ["./src"],
   transform: {
     "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest"
   },
   moduleNameMapper: {
     "@helpers/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/helpers/$1",
     "@root/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
   },
   ...
 }
```

Now, we need to take care of the build process because `tsc` is not capable of transpiling aliases to their relative siblings.

To do that we will use `tscpaths` package: https://github.com/joonhocho/tscpaths . This one is simple.

So considering your build command was just:

```
tsc
```

Now it becomes

```
tsc && tscpaths -p tsconfig.json -s ./src -o ./dist/server
```

You need to adjust your `-s` and `-o` to your structure, but when you inspect your `.js` file after build you should see if the relative path is correctly linked (and debug accordingly).

That's it. It should work as ace. It's a lot but it's worth it.

**Example of a call in the controller (.ts) and in React component (.tsx) file:**

```
import { IApiResponse } from '@intf/IApi'
```

Comment: "moduleNameMapper" is what did it for me, thank you for the reply!

Comment: @JeanCosta Yes, adding `moduleNameMapper` fixed it!

Answer (score 5):

In my case to support @Greg Wozniak's answer, I only needed to fix my jest config file.

My app uses `jest.config.ts`

In my  `src/index.ts` I have `import "module-alias/register"`

In `package.json`:

```
{
   ...
   "_moduleAliases": {
     "@helpers": "dist/helpers",
     "@root": "dist"
   }
}
```

In `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    ...
    "paths": {
      "@helpers/*": ["helpers/*"],
      "@root/*": ["*"]
      ...
    }
 }
```

In `jest.config.ts`:

- added roots, preset, the `(.*)` and `$1` signs in moduleNameMapper*

```
{
   roots: [
        "<rootDir>/src/"
    ],
    preset: "ts-jest",
   transform: {
        "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest",
    },
   moduleNameMapper: {
     "@helpers/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/helpers/$1",
     "@root/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
   },
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have the routes properly configured in your `tsconfig`, since the paths lack the `src` folder (while they appear in your package.json module alias config):

Your `tsconfig` code:

```
"@config/*": ["config/*"],
"@interfaces/*": ["interfaces/*"],
"@services/*": ["services/*"]
```

How I think it should be:

```
"@config/*": ["src/config/*"],
"@interfaces/*": ["src/interfaces/*"],
"@services/*": ["src/services/*"]
```

Comment: It seems the baseUrl in compilerOptions could informs the compiler where to find modules because It gives me typescript error after I added 'src' into the path

Comment: I can't even start my app, it also gives me Cannot find module '@config/...'

Comment: wow that really puzzles me. I have a working configuration with ts and jest, and I am specifying the full route to my paths indicating the `src` segment. I see that in your package.json you're referring to 'interface' , but in your tsconfig there's a reference to 'interfaces'  instead (with the extra `s`). Maybe it is related, I'm not sure.

Comment: I created a jest.config.js and added two options including 'roots' and 'transform' then everything works fine now.